# inserting new element into byte array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration

```
private byte[] splitKeyAlgorithm(byte[] key) {
        var splitStream = 55;
        for (int i = 0, x = 0; i < key.length; i++, x++) {
            if (x == splitStream) {
                key[i] = '\n';
                x = -1;
            }
        }
        return key;
    }
```

I want to split array of bytes to print into this same length line by new line byte '\n'(splitStream). My question is: I have elegant splitted byte array on the screen but what does with element represented by **key[i]** ? Is overwritten by '\n'? Its impossible because i do:

```
Arrays.compare(original byte[], splitted byte[]);
Arrays.mismatch(original byte[], splitted byte[]);
```

Above codes return that this two arrays are equals and don't have any mismatch.

**Edit://**
Comparing looks like this:

```
Arrays.compare(List<ByteArrayOutputStream>outputStream.get(0).toByteArray(), primitive byte[] array);
```

Comment: It is overwritten with the char value of `\n`. If there was no `\n` at that place before (which it wasn't, because `\n` is `10` and not `55`), the two arrays are not equal (unless they are both empty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the same array. Hence `original == splitted`.

```
private byte[] splitKeyAlgorithm(byte[] key) {
    var lineLength = 55;
    int copyLength = key.length + key.length / lineLength;
    byte[] copy = new byte[copyLength];
    int ci = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i += lineLength) {
        int i2 = Math.min(i + lineLength, key.length);
        System.arraycopy(key, i, copy, ci, i2 - i);
        ci += i2 - i;
        if (ci < copy.length) {
            copy[ci++] = '\n';
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are destroying your array now.

Instead you should make a new array with enough extra bytes for the inserted characters:

```
int splitStream=55;
byte[] copy=new byte[key.length+key.length/splitStream];
int kidx=0,ccount=0;
for(int i=0;i<copy.length;i++){
  if(ccount==splitStream){
    ccount=0;
    copy[i]='\n';
  } else {
    ccount++;
    copy[i]=key[kidx];
    kidx++;
  }
}
return copy;
```

... probably, but I have not tested it.

Now I did. Fixed the `count`-`ccount` typos, and there is a test here: https://ideone.com/efDvE2

Comment: It have sense but both arrays are equals before and after splitting.

Comment: @Matthew see the full test on https://ideone.com/efDvE2, it does not seem to lose data (the entire sequence survives, plus the line breaks appear).

Comment: Yeah I saw it. Thanks but I can't find answer on my question. Are my arrays are equals: first - before splitting, and second - after splitting. Wtf?

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting the '\n' into the array, you are overwriting whatever on key[i] was.

It could be, the Arrays.compare returns 0 (equal) because there where already '\n' on those positions?

Comment: It's impossible. Byte arrays passed to this method is random RSA algorithm encoded by BASE64.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Original array before splitting was overwritten and element byte[55] on original and new array = 10, so this is my '\n'. Confusion was by comparing which was performed after splitting and both object was identical. Good lesson for me. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Good catch.  To clarify, there is only one `byte[]` object here and both `original` and `splitted` are point to it.  As a result the comparison will always match.  You'll need to clone/copy the array object to perform a real before-to-after comparison.